# How to display images correctly on Flutter Web (stored on Firebase)?

Tags: firebase, image, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am making my first Flutter Web page and it will be mainly a photo portfolio, with a few extra functions on the page. Now I have stored the images on Firebase (Storage) and displayed the first pictures. Now I have several problems. First, the photos have not all the same pixel size. That means, that every photo has a different size on the web page. Second, I have some photos, that are pixelated and have a really bad resolution. Is there a possibility to have more control over the size of the picture and if it is pixelated or not?

Comment: As a developer you have total control of size and quality of a picture. Do you have a coding specific question and some code you can include that you're having difficulty with? Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you have already resolved your issue, but since there isn't an answer posted, I'll add my take here.

> Is there a possibility to have more control over the size of the
> picture and if it is pixelated or not?

Having more control over the size of the image is likely the easier of the two to answers, and can be done in so many ways that I can't really say. For my example, I will use a Container.

- Off the top of my head, you can also use SizedBox(), ConstrainedBox(), and even limit the size of images if you have rows with assigned height, etc.

Use a container, using a set width and height. This will limit the image to the size of the container. However, depending on the aspect ratio of the image, you may have space at the top and bottom of the container, or on the sides.

```
Container(
  width: 150,
  height: 150,
  Image.asset("assetPath")
)
```

Use a Container, but also set the image size. This will force the image to be exactly 100x100 pixels.

```
Container(
  width: 150,
  height: 150,
  Image.asset("assetPath",
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
  )
)
```

If you wanted to center the 100x100 image, you can use the container's alignment property, like so.

```
Container(
  width: 150,
  height: 150,
  alignment: alignment: Alignment.center,
  Image.asset("assetPath",
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
  )
)
```

Image assets also have a fit property, which can be used to determine how your image should be fit inside of a container. Note that I have removed the width and height parameters of the Image asset. They aren't required here, and I wouldn't use them when using a fit.

BoxFit.cover makes the image as small as possible while still covering the entire target box. There are other fit options as well, such as fitting width, fitting height, etc.

```
Container(
  width: 150,
  height: 150,
  alignment: alignment: Alignment.center,
  Image.asset("assetPath",
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  )
)
```

One of the last items refers to quality, though, to be honest, I have never been able to really figure out how to get images to the best quality. I think the best option is to have an image as close to the size you want it on the screen, so flutter doesn't have to make many adjustments. For example, I have a picture that is 2048x296, and when using it in flutter at 300x80, and it came out terrible. Though, If I used a different application to make the image smaller, closer to 300x80, it looks much better.

At any rate, there is a Filter parameter. However, most of the time, setting no filter is just as good as setting it to high. Hopefully they will provide something for this in the near future.

```
Image.asset("assetPath",
  filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,
)
```

As a tip, I typically wrap images and text in a FittedBox(). Since this is a web app, and you'll be resizing the screen, a FittedBox will allow for dynamic resizing. With text, it even adjusts the font size automatically. The Flutter team hit this one out of the park.

```
FittedBox(
  fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
  Container(
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    alignment: alignment: Alignment.center,
    Image.asset("assetPath",
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    )
  )
)
```

The scaleDown option ONLY allows the content to scale down (obviously). This is particularly nice for text. Using a FittedBox with text, without scaleDown, will enlarge to the size of the container.

As for quality, there aren't a whole lot of options that I've found, but I suppose I haven't looked a lot. The best option that I found, to reiterate, is to get the image to the size you'd prefer before adding it, and use SVG files whenever you can. SVG files are drawn on the screen using vectors and mathematics, so they will never be pixelated.